# Footer for magazine website does bit RWD

Tags: html, css, performance, footer

Am trying to re-create a **footer** that will resize for different mobile devices. So far my **footer** looks great in larger screen views, but once it goes smaller ... the text blows out of background color.

I cannot seem to get the proper css & div's code to all work together properly. I do have the meta data correct for the head & body, but the footer seems to act alone.

Here is my link: http://www.freewebs.com/awordfitlyspoken/frontpage.htm
Would really appreciate advice and proper sequence of css & div's coding.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of extraneous elements in your code. There also seem to be a few different issues going on, so it's tough to tell what exactly you are trying to fix.

I can better help you if you copy and paste your HTML/CSS into a codepen (http://codepen.io/pen/) and then share the link with me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Himmel ... Yes, this version of my html has many extraneous elements. I do have another version which I cleaned up in www.dirtymarkup.com/. But I wanted to get through these issues with my footer area first. Here is the link as you asked for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNNZoz     THANK YOU for your assistance.

Comment: I see this is your first time posting to stackoverflow, welcome! It's much easier if you isolate ONLY the relevant HTML/CSS (the portions that pertain to the footer). As with any large system, it's tough to fix a problem when there are a lot of moving parts. It would be much easier for me to help you if you could do this.

Comment: Also note that it is generally considered bad practice to embed your styles into the HTML via `style` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I am going to clean up the html first and then try to address problems ... later. It is all just too overwhelming to do all at once. I  can see I have a lot to learn & will try step by step ... Thank you again very much for your time and your comments.